# blender importing three.js library

Tags: import, three.js, blender

I have a problem while three.js library importing to Blender. I m using Blender 2.78 version. And I followed this steps...https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender 
I tried to set up Blender programming.But still take this error."importer not include"  Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/macLl.png)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to import a model from three.js JSON-format into blender? Unfortunately that isn't supported. The message in blender is normal.

The only way I know of that (kindof) works is to use the THREE.OBJExporter to convert the mesh into the Wavefront OBJ-format which blender can read.

As the documentation says right at the bottom:
**Currently there is no import functionality available.**

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender#importer

Comment: Hi Mr.Martin;   In fact my project to do 3D racing game with three.js. The game will be a game on the web. I have designed a track in the renderer and I need to access the three.js (json) format. I tried to export it. I'm trying to get an ordinary cub, how many days. I choose scene, light, materials and cameras. I'm getting the codes below.
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfUDY.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwGNm.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oF6U.png

Comment: When I looked at several projects, the codes did not come up like this. In addition, three.js was successfully imported (there are no exclamations on those projects). Maybe the error might be from "include not found". I am not sure whether I will go to the index.html page and whether it is the correct path. this is the way the code is supposed to come? Can you continue if you say no error in Blender?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I'm not sure if maybe an older version of the plugin came with an import-funcionality tbh. However, the error-message you get from blender is simply saying something like: "I did load this plugin and I can use it to export data into that format but there is no importer in this plugin so I can't import data from that format".

Comment: The screenshots of the json file shows that you have exported from blender. If this fails to work in a browser then ask another question showing your html, js and json and ask why you can't see the 3D in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the screenshot of your addon preferences, you have the three.js export addon installed and enabled, the "Importer not included" is only an informational message provided by the addon. You can see the message in the addon code [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/blender/addons/io_three/__init__.py#L46)

Comment: So that's not a mistake, is it? Just a notice. I understand. I do not think it's a problem if we do not import. We will "export" for now.Thank you Mr.Sambler...